# How do I add beans dynamically in code in a Spring (Boot) application?

Tags: spring, rabbitmq

I have a Spring (boot) application that's using spring-rabbit, and I create the binding beans as needed like so:

```
import org.springframework.amqp.core.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class QueueBindings {

    // first binding

    @Bean
    public Queue firstQueue(@Value("${rabbitmq.first.queue}") String queueName) {
        return new Queue(queueName);
    }

    @Bean
    public FanoutExchange firstExchange(@Value("${rabbitmq.first.exchange}") String exchangeName) {
        return new FanoutExchange(exchangeName);
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding firstBinding(Queue firstQueue, FanoutExchange firstExchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(firstQueue).to(firstExchange);
    }

    // second binding

    @Bean
    public Queue secondQueue(@Value("${rabbitmq.second.queue}") String queueName) {
        return new Queue(queueName);
    }

    @Bean
    public FanoutExchange secondExchange(@Value("${rabbitmq.second.exchange}") String exchangeName) {
        return new FanoutExchange(exchangeName);
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding secondBinding(Queue secondQueue, FanoutExchange secondExchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(secondQueue).to(secondExchange);
    }

}
```

The issue I have is that there are only two pieces of information per 3 beans, the queue name and the exchange name.

Is there a way to add an arbitrary number of beans to the context rather than copy and paste a bunch of `@Bean` methods? I'd want something like "for each name in this list, add these three beans with this connection."

Answer (score 0):

To register an arbitrary number of beans programatically, you need to drop down to a lower-level API. You can use `@Import` on a configuration class to reference an `ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar` implementation. In the `registerBeanDefinitions` method of the registrar, you'd then register bean definitions for all of the beans.

If you want to be able to externally configure the beans that will be registered, an `ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar` can be `EnvironmentAware`. This allows you to have the `Environment` injected so that you can use its properties to customise the beans that your registrar will register.

Comment: I've finally gotten around to trying this approach. The problem I'm running into is that `Environment` doesn't let you treat properties like maps; you can ask for a known property but you can't ask for "all values under this property treating it as a dotted path". Spring Boot has the ability to map to Maps, but I don't know how to access other beans from within the registrar.